# Redisson config setBeanFactory autowiring beans

Tags: redis, redisson

I have a task class defined here:

```
{

    @Autowired
    private CarPainter carpainter;

    private String color;
    private Car car;


    public CarPainterTask(Car car, String color)
    {
        this.car = car;
        this.color = color;
    }


    public Car call()
    {

        if(car.getColor().equals(color))
        {
            return car;
        }

    carPainter.paint(car);  

        return car;
    }

}
```

I want to be able to `@Autowired` a service into my task class but also be able to put in some parameters

I've tried creating a `@Configuration` class for my Redisson node

```
    @Bean
    public RedissonNode createRedissonWorker()
    {
        RedissonNodeConfig nodeConfig = new RedissonNodeConfig(redissonClient.getConfig());
        nodeConfig.setExecutorServiceWorkers(Collections.singletonMap("carService", 1));
        nodeConfig.setBeanFactory(applicationContext);
        RedissonNode node = RedissonNode.create(nodeConfig);
        node.start();
        return node;
    }
```

And having Redisson inject `CarPainter` bean from Springboot's bean container, but this doesn't work...

Is there a way to achieve what I need here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `createRedissonWorker()` method use the `BeanFactory` instance to pass it to `setBeanFactory()` instead of the `ApplicationContext` and it should work just fine.

Comment: a bit late for me, but thanks for responding, i moved on to quartz anyway

Comment: I have actually done that but still getting the bean not found.
      Config config = new Config();
        config.useSingleServer().setAddress("redis://" + redisHost + ":" + redisPort + "");
        RedissonNodeConfig nodeConfig = new RedissonNodeConfig(config);
        nodeConfig.setExecutorServiceWorkers(Collections.singletonMap("myExecutor", 1));
        nodeConfig.setBeanFactory(beanFactory);
        RedissonNode node = RedissonNode.create(nodeConfig);
        node.start();
        return node;